# Understanding bquote in r

Tags: r, side-effects

This should be simple but I cannot understand what is going on:

```
> m <- 6
> bquote(risk.(m) <- risk[list(.(m))])
risk.(m) <- risk[list(6)]
```

Why did it not return

```
risk6 <- risk[list(6)]
```

which is what I was trying to achieve? I have read the documentation and do not know what I am missing.

Comment: `?bquote` says `"terms wrapped in .() are evaluated in the specified 'where' environment."`

Comment: `risk.` is a syntactically valid symbol. `bquote` is not `sprintf`. However, this looks like an xy-problem. What you are trying to achieve is not something you should need.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you just need to put in a valid separator between `risk` and the call to `.()`:

```
> m <- 6
> bquote(risk*.(m) <- risk[list(.(m))])
risk * 6 <- risk[list(6)]
```

If that were passed to a plotmath call for a plot title or other annotation, then I thought it would display: "risk6 <- risk.subscript(6)". However it displayed it in functional notation: `<-(risk6, risk.subscript(6) )`.  If solving the syntactic problem was not what you needed help on, then you should explain what you have for values of your `risk`-object and expand on what the endgame might be.

```
png(height=200); plot(1,1,main=bquote(risk*.(m) <- risk[list(.(m))]) ); dev.off()
```

[image]

Sometimes you get a different result with `substitute`, but in this case the results are the same with:

```
plot(1,1,main=substitute(risk*m <- risk[list(m)], list(m=6)) )
```

... and things are even more amusing with:

```
plot(1,1,main=as.character(substitute(risk*m <- risk[list(m)], list(m=6))) )
```

So ... I think you need to quote the assignment operator is you want to suppress the interpretation of `<-` as a function.:

```
png(height=200); plot(1,1,main=bquote(risk*.(m)~"<-"~risk[list(.(m))]) ); dev.off()
```

[image]